OOB Statistics for ENVI Random Forest Classifier
I am running the Random Forest Classifier in the ENVI Machine Learning module. In the settings, there is a tick box for Out-of-Bag (OOB) Score. When you hover over the OOB Score text it says, "Specify whether to use out-of-bag samples to estimate the generalization score. The score will be stored in the OUTPUT_MODEL statistics report.".
After running the classification, I can not find any sign of a statistics report or any information on OOB Score. The three files produced are the raster, an .enp file, and a header file (.hdr). I can't find anything in the raster's metadata about OOB statistics.
Does anyone know if this OOB score is actually produced? And if so, where I might find it?
